# Make the text of the magic link [genai.se] explicit (use GenAI SE or GenAI Stack Exchange instead of GenAI)

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Please make sure to refer to the magic link for the main site, `[genai.se]` as either `GenAI SE` or `GenAI Stack Exchange` instead of just `GenAI`. This will make the text more clear.

Comment: What is magic link?

Comment: @holydragon "Magic link" is a term used by the "elders" (some of the SO/SE "power users" and staff) are markdown shorthands that are parsed as hyperlinks. I suggested a tag wiki for [meta-tag:magic-links] including few shorthand examples.  The the help article about the markdown has some examples too.

Comment: @holydragon Magic links are shortcuts for links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/237701